# Serial read only returns reverse question marks in Blutooth connection read

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm facing problem with my Arduino Bluetooth controller car.
I'm only getting reverse question marks.

I'm using an HC-05 Bluetooth module. The pins are connected as following:

- HC 05 -> Arduino
- RX -> TX
- TX -> RX
- 5V -> 5V
- GND -> GND

Ardunio code:

```cpp
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor right_motor(3, MOTOR12_8KHZ);
AF_DCMotor left_motor(4, MOTOR12_8KHZ);

String readString;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  right_motor.setSpeed(250);
  left_motor.setSpeed(250);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    delay(50);
    char c=Serial.read();
    readString+=c;
  }
  if(readString.length()>0){
    Serial.println(readString);
    if (readString =="FORWARD"){
      right_motor.run (FORWARD);
      left_motor.run (FORWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="BACKWARD"){
      right_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      left_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="LEFT"){
      right_motor.run (FORWARD);
      left_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="RIGHT"){
      right_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      left_motor.run (FORWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="STOP"){
      right_motor.run (RELEASE);
      left_motor.run (RELEASE);
      delay(500);
    }

    readString="";
  }
}
```

Serial monitor:

[image: Serial monitor output]

I have tried many types of changes in the code, but they are not working.

Comment: Th reasons people usually get false serial data: 1- Baud rates don't match 2-Serial is busy doing something else. Are you sure you have set the baud rate of your Bluetooth module to 9600?

Comment: @TheEngineer Yes 9600.

Comment: use Serial.readString() instead of Serial.read()

Comment: Are you sure your Bluetooth module runs at 9600?

Comment: no not sure @gre_gor how to check?

Answer (score 0):

The baud rates must be identical between Bluetooth module and Arduino Serial port. You can check the Bluetooth module baud rate by entering the following AT command:
`AT+UART?`, also, you can change it using the following AT command: `AT+UART=desired_baud_rate, stop_bit, parity_bit,\r\n`.

Moreover, you can't use `Serial.read()` then compare the output with `"STRING"`! Instead, use `Serial.readString();`.

Answer (score 0):

According to most documentation, the default baud rate for HC-05 is 9600, or 38400 for AT command mode. Try:

```
Serial.begin(57600);
```

I've got a half dozen HC-05 which all shipped with a default set to 57600 baud.

*(I'm posting this answer in part because I just spent hours re-discovering this.)*